# Linux date command, format without format?

Tags: linux, date, format, locale, strftime

I am developing my locale and need to debug on different notions of [date](https://man.archlinux.org/man/date.1). I use the the format string to show different notations. How can I add the *ordinary* notation into the format string?

```
% LANG=en_HK.UTF-8 date '+ (%%Ec) %Ec %n (%%r ) %r %n (%%c ) %c %n (ref) %F %T wk %U at %u' ; date
 (%Ec) Fri Jun 24 13:54:39 2022 
 (%r ) 01:54:39 PM 
 (%c ) Fri Jun 24 13:54:39 2022 
 (ref) 2022-06-24 13:54:39 wk 25 at 5
Fri Jun 24 13:54:39 HKT 2022
```

Comment: `ordinary notation` Which one is it? What do you mean? `into the format string?` Into which one? If you want to modify the output of `%Ec`, then modify specific field in the locale. https://lh.2xlibre.net/values/era_d_t_fmt/  `I use the the format string to show different notation` Use `locale LC_TIME`. | I do not understand what exactly you want to add and where. Which output exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: For example, if `date '+%@'` gives the same output as `date`, `%@` is the answer I am looking for. So I can append `%@` into `date '+ (format A) %Ec %n (format B ) %r %n (ordinary format) %@'`

Comment: I do not understand - `%@` is invalid specifier. Anyway, https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/date.c#L545 -> https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/date.c#L120 . And the last `date` call doesn't explicitly set `LANG`, did you actually set the locale?

Comment: I know `%@` is invalid. I made it up, just for an example.

Comment: .. -> https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2016-April/070097.html . It seems that you want to modify `LC_TIME.date_fmt` field in your locale. And I do not think there is a `date` format specifier for it. You can append `date "+$(locale LC_TIME | sed '25!d')"`

Comment: Yes you are right. I modified both `d_t_fmt` and `date_fmt`. `date '+%c'` gives my modified version in `d_t_fmt`, while I cannot find a format specifier for `date_fmt`.